# Anko: inner scope of apply, confusing property resolution

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm writing an Android layout using Anko DSL.
When defining a `TextView`, I wanted to make it center-aligned, so I wrote this:

```
verticalLayout {
    textView(R.string.txt_greeting).apply {
        gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL // <- this should have changed the alignment
        textSize = 20.0f
    }
    //...
}
```

But the alignment didn't change. In debugger I saw that gravity is set for the `LinearLayout` which is the `TextView`'s parent.

Changing the statement to either

```
textView(R.string.txt_greeting).let { it.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL }
```

and

```
textView(R.string.txt_greeting).apply { this@apply.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL }
```

and even

```
textView(R.string.txt_greeting).apply { this.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL }
```

solves the problem, thus in the original code implicit `this` is definitely resolved to `this@verticalLayout`.

Why does this happen?

Do I misunderstand something in Kotlin lambdas or is it a bug in Kotlin or Anko?

Comment: It seems like a bug. I filed an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a bug in scoping.

The [corresponding issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10219#tab=Changes) has been marked as fixed, so the fix is likely to appear in the next release.